# Re-directing URLs with dates to URLs without dates

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect

When I first started writing entries I decided to include the month and day in the URL's, thinking I might need them. In the end turns out I didn't.

I found that I can access a particular entry as

```
http://myblog.com/2013/02/16/my-entry
http://myblog.com/my-entry
```

Typing in the second one would simply lead to a 301 redirect to the first.

Is there a way to make it so that typing in the long form with the date would re-direct to the second without breaking any permalinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set your permalinkstructure to `/%postname%/`.

Special rewrite rules do not need to be done here, as this is a simple setting WordPress handles on it's own.

Comment: is it ok to change the format even after entries have been created and permalinks posted in other places? I am under the assumption that I'd have to stick with whatever I set in the beginning.

Comment: WordPress redirects them accordingly. You can just try it out, and if something goes wrong, switch back. Should be no problem.